# What does 'lying around" mean when working on a task?

Tags: idiom-meaning

Could someone please explain what does 'lying around' mean in the following contexts?

1. I just updated the essay for the one I had lying around.
2. Here is a study I had lying around for a while.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure that the first example is a good one - where did you find it? The second is fine. -- If, in this figurative context you say that something is lying around (also lying **about**), it indicates that you did not attach much importance or value to the object, and so did not put it in a secure position or did not take particular note of exactly where it was. It is also used to indicate that you cannot remember where it is, although you know (or think) that it is somewhere in a particular vicinity. This is particularly true when you have not used the thing for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be physically lying around (as paper on a heap or shelf, in a cupboard) but usually means much more than mere physical presence.

In most usage it refers to the fact that it *had been prepared earlier for some reason, was perhaps never used for the original purpose, but is now suited to the present purpose*. As such it could be "lying around" in a computer. It is only metaphorically lying around.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the paper on which is written the essay, or the sheaf of papers, could be found in your near surroundings, for instance first on your desk, perhaps on a pile of books on your desk for a while and then as you moved it, later, in a drawer, from which still later you took it out to check something, which resulted in the bundle of papers to end up on the desk again, and so on; that's what lying around means, for sometime in one place, then in another and again in a new one, and so on.